# HTML table with 2 rows in its footer, one of them scrolling the other one fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table with 2 rows in its footer, the vertical and horizontal scroll work fine, but I would like to keep one of the footer rows fixed (not scrolling at all), in order to show pagination controls.

I wonder if this is possible using only CSS.
I have tried changing the `display` and `position` properties to the second row, but without the expected results.

```css
/* Center the grid container */

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Grid style */

#grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 473px;
}


/* Table size */

table {
  height: 388px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tbody {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.caption {
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c6c6;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Columns style */

th {
  background: #b3b3b3 !important;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

th.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

td.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Header & Footer row style */

thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

tfoot {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="caption row justify-content-evenly">
      <h5 class="col-11">This is the caption</h5>
      <button id="closeBtn col" type="button" class="btn-close"></button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="fixed">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Double Bastard Ale</td>
          <td>Red Stripe</td>
          <td>Pilsner</td>
          <td>Newport</td>
          <td>1388 - Belgian Strong Ale</td>
          <td>Wheat mal</td>
          <td>2.8%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brooklyn Black</td>
          <td>Samuel Adams</td>
          <td>Stout</td>
          <td>Mt. Rainier</td>
          <td>2206 - Bavarian Lager</td>
          <td>Rye malt</td>
          <td>3.7%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>St. Bernardus Abt 12</td>
          <td>Paulaner</td>
          <td>Light Lager</td>
          <td>Liberty</td>
          <td>3278 - Belgian Lambic Blend</td>
          <td>Chocolate malt</td>
          <td>3.6%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Westmalle Trappist Tripel</td>
          <td>Samuel Adams</td>
          <td>India Pale Ale</td>
          <td>Equinox</td>
          <td>3942 - Belgian Wheat</td>
          <td>Caramel</td>
          <td>4.6%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trappistes Rochefort 8</td>
          <td>Pacifico</td>
          <td>German Wheat And Rye Beer</td>
          <td>Mt. Hood</td>
          <td>3278 - Belgian Lambic Blend</td>
          <td>Carapils</td>
          <td>7.9%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>La Fin Du Monde</td>
          <td>Harp</td>
          <td>Light Hybrid Beer</td>
          <td>Cashmere</td>
          <td>5112 - Brettanomyces bruxellensis</td>
          <td>Chocolate</td>
          <td>4.7%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sierra Nevada Celebration Ale</td>
          <td>Red Stripe</td>
          <td>Belgian And French Ale</td>
          <td>Willamette</td>
          <td>1332 - Northwest Ale</td>
          <td>Caramel</td>
          <td>8.0%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="fixed"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="8">
            <span>Records per page:</span>
            <span>
                           <select id="recordsPage">
                              <option value="10">10</option>
                              <option value="25">25</option>
                              <option value="50">50</option>
                              <option value="75">75</option>
                              <option value="100">100</option>
                           </select>
                        </span>
            <span>1-10</span><span> of </span><span>1000</span>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">First</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Previous</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Next</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Last</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider placing the pagination controls *outside* the table

Comment: DarkBee I did, but it looks horrible and confusing for the users to find the horizontal scroll bar in between the table and the pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but it is kind of hacky as hell.

Put the footer content in the first `td` then have an empty `td` that spans the other columns. Give your footer td `position:sticky; left:0;` and (importantly) `white-space:nowrap` since we want the content to expand out of its cell and be stuck to the side.

EG:

```css
/* Center the grid container */

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Grid style */

#grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 473px;
}


/* Table size */

table {
  height: 388px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tbody {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.caption {
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c6c6;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Columns style */

th {
  background: #b3b3b3 !important;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

th.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

td.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Header & Footer row style */

thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

tfoot td.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  right: auto;
  left:0;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="caption row justify-content-evenly">
      <h5 class="col-11">This is the caption</h5>
      <button id="closeBtn col" type="button" class="btn-close"></button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="fixed">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Double Bastard Ale</td>
          <td>Red Stripe</td>
          <td>Pilsner</td>
          <td>Newport</td>
          <td>1388 - Belgian Strong Ale</td>
          <td>Wheat mal</td>
          <td>2.8%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brooklyn Black</td>
          <td>Samuel Adams</td>
          <td>Stout</td>
          <td>Mt. Rainier</td>
          <td>2206 - Bavarian Lager</td>
          <td>Rye malt</td>
          <td>3.7%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>St. Bernardus Abt 12</td>
          <td>Paulaner</td>
          <td>Light Lager</td>
          <td>Liberty</td>
          <td>3278 - Belgian Lambic Blend</td>
          <td>Chocolate malt</td>
          <td>3.6%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Westmalle Trappist Tripel</td>
          <td>Samuel Adams</td>
          <td>India Pale Ale</td>
          <td>Equinox</td>
          <td>3942 - Belgian Wheat</td>
          <td>Caramel</td>
          <td>4.6%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trappistes Rochefort 8</td>
          <td>Pacifico</td>
          <td>German Wheat And Rye Beer</td>
          <td>Mt. Hood</td>
          <td>3278 - Belgian Lambic Blend</td>
          <td>Carapils</td>
          <td>7.9%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>La Fin Du Monde</td>
          <td>Harp</td>
          <td>Light Hybrid Beer</td>
          <td>Cashmere</td>
          <td>5112 - Brettanomyces bruxellensis</td>
          <td>Chocolate</td>
          <td>4.7%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sierra Nevada Celebration Ale</td>
          <td>Red Stripe</td>
          <td>Belgian And French Ale</td>
          <td>Willamette</td>
          <td>1332 - Northwest Ale</td>
          <td>Caramel</td>
          <td>8.0%</td>
          <td class="fixed"><button class="editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="fixed"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" class="fixed">
            <span>Records per page:</span>
            <span>
                           <select id="recordsPage">
                              <option value="10">10</option>
                              <option value="25">25</option>
                              <option value="50">50</option>
                              <option value="75">75</option>
                              <option value="100">100</option>
                           </select>
                        </span>
            <span>1-10</span><span> of </span><span>1000</span>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">First</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Previous</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Next</button>
            <button class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2">Last</button>
          </td>
          <td colspan="7"></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

But why bother? You could just put the pagination content in a `div` *outside* of the `table` rather than in the `tfoot`.

Comment: That's exactly how I wanted it to work. Thanks @Moob. Ehmm... yes, I used to have the pagination in a div outside of the table, but it really looks weird with the horizontal scroll bar in the middle of them. That's why I wanted to try a new style, in order to improve its look and feel.